# Request for the existence of links

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make a quick selection and get the number of those users who have already invited at least someone?
I tried, suffered, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) as `count` 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.id=u.ref 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=u1.ref
```

You need to make 1 sql, and it turns out that only the `id` and `ref` columns are used.
Those users who haven't invited anyone shouldn't be in the count.

Is it possible to do this or will it be necessary to use cycles and make more requests?

[structure is simple](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6553d7) - you need to get those who have invited at least someone

For this structure, it should look like this:

1 - invited? Yes!
2 - invited? Yes!
3 - invited? No!
4 - invited? Yes!
5 - invited? Yes!
6 - invited? Yes!
7 - invited? No!

Only 5.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What value is in the ref column when the user has NOT invited someone?

Comment: Why are you joining back to users twice?  U is the person, u1 is the users that person invited, what's u2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer was based on an unclear definition of how ref was used.  This should give you what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id) as `count` 
FROM users u 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u1 WHERE u1.ref = u.id)
```